# À quelle syllabe correspond le plus d'homonymes ?

Tags: prononciation, lexique, homonymes

Par exemple :

> Le son **[tɑ̃]** --> taon, tant, temps, t'en.
>
> Le son **[mεʁ]** --> mère, mer, maire
>
> Le son **[vεʁ]** --> ver, vair, verre, vers

Aussi :

> Conte, Comte et Compte

Y a-t-il des syllabes avec plus de quatre homonymes ?

Comment: ces ses c'est s'est sais sait

Comment: Il y a aussi *tan* et *vert*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repris des commentaires :

« O » semble prendre la première place avec 7 homophonies :

- oh
- ô
- eau
- au
- aulx
- os
- haut

auxquels on peut ajouter les pluriels :

- eaux
- aux
- hauts

Comment: Il y a aussi _ho_ de _ho hisse_

Answer (score 1):

En faisant abstraction des variations ouvert/fermé selon la région des locuteurs, et sans compter les pluriels et conjugaisons:

- et
- est
- ai
- hais
- hé
- eh
- haie

Answer (score 1):

Ex-æquo avec les huit « O » si on accepte les variations régionales [e] / [ɛ], il y a « LÉ » :

- lai
- laid
- laie
- lait
- lez
- les
- lès
- lé

et les pluriels

- lais
- laids
- laies
- laits
- lés